# App Maker: How I can connect and sync with Google Contacts

Tags: google-app-maker

How I can connect and sync with Google Contacts? How do I use google calendar?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple example that shows how to add a Contact to your Google Account using App Maker. For this, I am using the “addToGroup(group)” method as explained here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#addtogroupgroup

1. Create a new App Maker application.
2. Add a new Server Script to your App Maker app and add the following code:

> ```
> function addContact() {
>  // The code below creates a new contact and then adds it to the contact group named
>  // "My Contacts"
>  var contact = ContactsApp.createContact('John', 'Doe', 'john.doe@example.com');
>  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts');
>  contact = contact.addToGroup(group);
> }
> ```

3. Create a new "Page" in App Maker and add a Button widget
4. Select the Button widget and using the Property editor, choose "onClick" > Custom Action
5. Add the following code to the onClick custom action:

> ```
> function onSuccess() {   
> console.log("New Contact added succesfully"); 
> }
> google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).addContact();
> ```

Note that in order to call a server script, you will need to use google.script.run as explained here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#call_a_server_script

6. Preview you App Maker application
7. Click the Button widget and the new contact will be added under "My Contacts" here https://contacts.google.com/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you
you have been very kind
I will try to start from Your have a full integration of google
contacts
Thanks again

Comment: a great help
but if I wanted to have all my contacts in the app maker and you can edit them?

Answer (score 0):

App Maker runs on Apps Script. So you can write a server-side script using the normal Apps Script APIs to accomplish this. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not good with scripts
you create me a small example to integrate calendar and contacts
thanks anyway